# Nothing happen When I use the method setBounds with JButton and JLabel

Tags: java, layout, background, jbutton, jlabel

when i use `setBounds();` on `JLabel` or `JButton`  nothing happen ?

```
public Window() {

    this.setExtendedState(Window.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(Window.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setUndecorated(true);          
    hideMoue();

    JLabel back=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("D:\\Java\\stone\\background.png"));
    add(back);
    back.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    l1=new JLabel("Label");
    b1=new JButton("Button");
    l1.setBounds(483, 513, 400, 60);
    l1.setBounds(483, 443, 400, 60);
    back.add(l1);
    back.add(b1);

    setSize(1366,768);  

    setVisible(true);

}
```

i think the problem in the **layout manager** but i can not find the solution  !!

Comment: You need to express what you are expecting and what actually happens.

Comment: What would you expect to happen? Why do you have a constructor Window() and you are using constants Window.MAXIMIZED_BOTH, further you are using setSize? Can you make an SSCCE if you want some help?

Comment: I want to design a welcome screen of  game 
But I faced problem with background when i use JLabel as a background 
the other jlabel and button dos not Appear !

Comment: Do you want a SplashScreen?

Comment: yes  i want SplashScreen

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected function for the Layout that you are using i.e `FlowLayout`. If you want `setBounds()` to take effect than `setLayout(null);` Having said this it is highly recommended not to use null layout. How the components are placed and arranged should be left with Layout Manager

Comment: but the background Will not appear ؟

Comment: i am sorry not background ,
the other button and jlabel  Will not appear if i set layout to null !

Answer (score 0):

Change your `back` JLabel to `null` layout.

```
...
JLabel back=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("D:\\Java\\stone\\background.png"));
add(back);
back.setLayout(null);    
...
```

Keep an eye on your second `setBounds()` command. You set both commands on `l1`.